# Apply CSS via JS

Tags: javascript, ios, css

guys,

I wrote the following script to add some padding above the navigation menu on http://www.mtscollective.com, but only when it's loaded as a web app (saved to the home screen) on iOS:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    (function menuPadding() {
        if (("standalone" in window.navigator) && window.navigator.standalone) {
            $('.menu-secondary').css('padding-top', '20px');
        };
    })();
</script>
```

However, it's not working, but I've confirmed that `window.navigator.standalone` is true with another script.

Any help would be really appreciated!